# AttributeError: module 'sparkdl' has no attribute 'graph'

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark

While I was working on jupyter on colab.research.google.com,
Codes are:

```
from sparkdl import DeepImageFeaturizer 
from sparkdl import readImages, DeepImagePredictor

predictor = DeepImagePredictor(inputCol="image", 
outputCol="predicted_labels",modelName="InceptionV3",decodePredictions=True, 
topK=10)
```

I keep receiving below error. What could be the problem?

```
"AttributeError: module 'sparkdl' has no attribute 'graph'"
```

Thank you

Comment: This seems to happen when using spark-deep-learning  1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11. Version 1.4.0 seems to load fine for me.